# What is the expected response to someone saying “Happy Vacations” to you?

Tags: politeness, conversation, valediction, non-native-english

Someone has messaged me: *Happy vacations*.

Are the following replies correct?

- Now it would be good.
- Same to you too!

Or should it be

- Same to you too!
- Now it would be good.

I want it to sound that my vacation will be all the better for his having mentioned it. What should the proper reply be?

Comment: One does not say *Happy Vacations* in English!

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Thank you, same to you*

is appropriate if someone is taking a vacation at the same time as you are. It is, in English, polite, understood to be appreciative, and adequate as a response. To say more is not common *in English*.

However cultures vary, and if your culture supports that style, then

> Thank you! Now that you've wished me well, I'm sure it will be awesome!

is fine. But the *same to you*, very common (and expected) in English would turn it into a mouthful.

If someone is *not* taking a vacation at the same time, clearly *same to you* is not useful. If you want to express gratitude beyond *thank you!*, you might say,

> *Thank you. I hope so, too."

Usually, in English (American, in any case), we don't say *Happy vacations*. We say, *have a nice/good/great vacation*, or *enjoy your vacation!*

Comment: Thanks! Can i say `Thanks! Now my vacations will definitely go awesome!
Happy vacations to you too!`?

Comment: Yes, it is a very kind response (*be* awsome, though, not *go* awesome). Not *common* in English, but I would be happy to receive this answer. :)

Comment: One more question.`What are you doing in your vacations?` or `What are you doing on your vacations?`
And is `Are you going for internship or training?` correct?

Comment: @user44475 [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: @Maverick - the second and third sentences are correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question was quite difficult to understand because of a number of grammatical and other errors. However I have edited it according to my interpretation and that may provide the necessary answer in itself.

For my part, I would probably say: 'Thank you; and the same to you'. Initially I wasn't entirely clear what you were getting at with 'Now it would be good'. Perhaps you mean 'Now you've wished it, it will be'. That sounds a bit unusual to me.

Comment: Thanks for edit. English is my second language. And I think the meaning of `Now it would be good` is same as you interpreted.

Comment: Actually, I thought the original was quite clearly stated,  conveying the intent better than your edit. It was not difficult to understand at all. I was tempted to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would respond *Thank you; likewise!*

Comment: What if the other person isn’t going anywhere, and it’s only you who’s being bidden *Bon voyage*? :)

Comment: @tchrist I'd simply respond "Merci!" :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the phrase "Happy vacations" is uttered on the brink of the New Year, the absolute inviolable tradition is to respond with "See you next year!"

If the phrase is uttered when you leave for vacations just before a holiday, you would felicitate the holiday like

- Happy 4th
- Chag Sameach (for Jews)
- Happy Deepavali

For Star Trekkies/Warries/Odysseyers/etc

- May the force be with you too.
- Resistance was futile, we will be rejuvenated.
- We will bring back a few little green men.
- Don't argue with me GAL, just open the door.
- I have not been up to par lately, but I can give you my complete assurance that I will be back to normal.
- We'll be back from the future.

For a girl you've been trying to hitch up

- Don't hold out for us, get married before we are back.
- Are you gonna ... you know ... before we return?

For other situations, a combination of the following ...

- Have fun while we're gone.
- Don't burn the house down.
- Are you guys gonna turn the office upside-down?
- Get pregnant already.
- Sorry for missing your baby shower.
- DON'T TEXT ME! Or email ME!!!
- Study hard.
- She is gonna say YES, before we return I assure you.
- I'll send you pictures.
- Follow us on our blog.
- Please take care of our dog, please.

Comment: Cute list!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​